# how to get first and last position of textview from horizontal scroll view

Tags: android

friend's

I have a horizontal scrollview with text fields,here i need to get the first and last position of textview when i scrolled it,how can i get the position of textview when i scrolled.and also need to know how to set color for text when i clicked the particular text from this.

sample code....

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/gv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="none" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <TextView android:id="@+id/music2" android:text="Music" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:textSize="15sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector" style="@style/FirstText"
                android:gravity="center"/>

                <TextView android:textColor="#000000" android:paddingLeft="10dip"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="|"/>

               <TextView android:id="@+id/movies2" android:text="Movies" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector" style="@style/FirstText"  android:gravity="center"/>

                <TextView android:textColor="#000000" android:paddingLeft="10dip"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="|"/>

               <TextView android:id="@+id/interview2" android:text="Interview" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="@drawable/selector" style="@style/FirstText"  android:gravity="center"/>

                <TextView  android:textColor="#000000" android:paddingLeft="10dip"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="|"/>
```

....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could get the y position with the getScrollY() method... keeping track of the position before/after scrolling would be done programmatically...

Comment: friend, 
   i can't clear about it,what override method i have to use to place it in that block,
for example for back button click event
  we can use back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListenr()){
..........
});

i need to know how to write it same for horizontalscrollview above my code ,i need to know what kind listener i have to use.help me.